# Custom CSS not working in Joomla Protostar template

Tags: css, joomla

I have not been able to get the custom css I entered in Joomla Protostar template to work. I created a new file (custom.css) under the "tempates: Customise" section in the Protostar template.  I input several css edits:

```
.nav menu{
  position: absolute;
}

page-header{
  display: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

I saved after each edit, returned to the front end, refreshed the page, and still nothing happens.  I read two other suggestions, one that said I need to save the link to the custom css file, which is http://graph-art.matc.edu/danied32/vicom124/joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_templates&view=template&id=506&file=L2Nzcy9jdXN0b20uY3Nz and load it in the head.php file.  I've been leery of doing that.  Any suggestions?  And yes, I am very new at this.

Comment: If you created a new "custom.css" file, you will need to link that file to your html file(s) - and in doing so, it needs to be under the pre-made css file link so that your custom.css file takes effect.

Example: In your html file(s), find in your `head` tags something that looks like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFileHere.css" />`  Then add your css file below that - So yours would look something similar to this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folderpath/custom.css" />`

Answer (score 1):

Since Joomla 3.5.0, the Protostar template loads custom CSS code from the file at `/templates/protostar/css/user.css`, if the file exists.

Renaming your `custom.css` to `user.css` should fix the issue.